# Login failed for user

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i keep having the below problem but i still do not have the solutions after spending a long time google-ing.

> Login failed for user 'FrienDev'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Login failed for user 'FrienDev'.

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'FrienDev'.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849719
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +144
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +342
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +44
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +45
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +20
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +57
>      System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +35
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +221
>      FrienDev.BusinessRules.UserRules.GetCurrentUser() +594
>      FrienDev.BusinessRules.UserRules.UpdateUserLoginInfomation() +66
>      FrienDev.BusinessRules.OnlineRules.UserLogin(String userId) +115
>      HandlerPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\TEST\FrienDevApps\FrienDevWeb\webauth-handler.aspx.cs:89
>      System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Anybody has any clue to that? 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? What code instruction give you this error? Can you post your code?

Without other info I think you don't have permission to connect to the database. Check your connectionstring and user credentials.